# which data structure is used in most popular databases?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, relational-database

i want to know which data structure(AVL, B-Tree, etc...) is used in most popular relational databases. and also in what way the data structure is superior than other in-class data structures? if possible a small comparison could help me a lot! thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's usually [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or variants thereof, primarily because it packs nodes into blocks, unlike binary trees such as AVL.

A node of a B-tree has a fixed maximum size and holds multiple keys and multiple pointers to child nodes, meaning fewer blocks need to be retrieved from disk to look up a value (compared to a binary tree).

The Wikipedia article on [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) has a good introduction from the angle of its application to databases.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server, there is background info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180978.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I would choose the B+ Selection Tree because it is appropriate for efficient insertion, deletion and range queries but if the database has not been changed since it was created, then a SIMPLE LINEAR INDEX is required